# Error when including boost.asio on Cygwin 64

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost.asio in my C++ project, using Cygwin 64-bit. However, even a program as simple as this:

```
// compiled by: g++ -g -std=c++11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -c -o build/server.o src/server.cpp

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

Causes a large stream of error messages. GCC complains that it cannot find symbols like `EAI_SERVICE`, `getaddrinfo`, or `host_name`. The full error log can be found here: https://pastebin.com/RwpX3bx3

In [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894006/how-to-use-boost-asio-library-with-cygwin-64-bit), it is suggested that I add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` to the command line. But, as you can see, I do compile it with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`, and it doesn't work. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling `libboost-devel` through the Cygwin installer, but that also did not work.

(EDIT: No, it doesn't work without `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`, either. Without it, you get this: https://pastebin.com/AExBa2pL)

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: What if you add `-D__POSIX_VISIBLE=200112`, and if that alone doesn't work, `-D__INSIDE_CYGWIN_NET__` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `-std=c++11` that restricts the scope for functions.
Without any restriction the compilation works fine.

```
$ g++ -c server.cpp -o server.o
$ ls -s server.o
164 server.o
```